# Problems installing spring greenhouse locally

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to install spring's greenhouse project and I am running into some errors.

This is the site I am working off:  [greenhouse](http://www.springsource.org/greenhouse/guide)

I was able to download the eclipse git plugin and install the project but it does not build.

My logs are

```
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: Maven Builder: FULL_BUILD 
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] 
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.springsource:greenhouse:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 418, column 12
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] 'distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.id' must not be 'local', this identifier is reserved for the local repository, using it for other repositories will corrupt your repository metadata. @ line 575, column 8
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] 
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] 
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] 
4/7/11 7:54:44 AM MST: [WARN] The POM for joda-time:joda-time-jsptags:jar:1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
4/7/11 7:54:45 AM MST: [WARN] The requested profile "greenhouse-embedded" could not be activated because it does not exist.
4/7/11 7:54:45 AM MST: Build errors for greenhouse; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) on project greenhouse: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar
```

I want to follow their mobile tutorials but I am stuck here.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a JDK, a JRE is not enougth.

May you need to change you environment variables (JAVA_HOME, PATH) , that they point to the JDK and not the JRE.

> Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar

`tools.jar` is in the `jdk\lib` directory, but not in the `jre6\lib` or `jdk\jre\lib`!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am not sure where that mapping is happening.  I went into the build path and removed jre and added jdk.  In my environment variables I have my java home variable point to the jdk and not the jre.

Comment: @blong824: does it work now? BTW: if you run this from eclipse, then you may need to specify the JDK in eclipse.ini too: `-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/javaw.exe`

Comment: No still no luck.  I updated elipse to point to the jdk and restarted but I have the same problems.

Comment: I am going to mark this as ther answer.  I haven't had a chance to test this out anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I too had this problem ("Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar"). Here are all the steps I did to have finally build my Greenhouse example from within Eclipse Indigo.

- Changed JAVA_HOME and PATH system variables and environmental variables to point to a current JDK installation.
- In my Windows 7 installation of Eclipse Indigo, under "Window" -> "Preferences" -> "Installed JREs" -> "Add..." -> JRE home: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29" (or whatever is currently available ... notice, it's a JDK, not a JRE).
- Still in the aforementioned "Edit JRE" dialog, selected "Add external JARs..." and selected  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\lib\tools.jar", so this JAR is also part of the "JRE system libraries".
- Back in the "Installed JREs" dialog, I removed all unnecessary JDK and JRE entries, keeping only the JDK1.6.0_29 I added in the steps before. Then check the checkbox of that entry.
- If not installed, installed the "SpringSource Tool Suite" (STS) into my existing Eclipse Indigo installation.
- in the STS "Dashboard", selected the "Extensions" tab, installed the "m2eclipse 1.0.100" extension.
- restarted my computer, restarted my Eclipse installation.
- if already imported, deleted the Greenhouse example.
- imported the Greenhouse example via File -> Import ... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects

Now everything builds well, and the example executed on my Jetty server within Eclipse.

Probably, some of the above steps are not necessary, but at least it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Step no. 2 in Abdull's answer solved it for me, no need to do the other steps.

Helios with SpringSource and m2e: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

I had it pointing to c:\program files\Java\jre7, changing it to c:\program files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13 solved the problem.